# Why are the results returned using a subquery different than when querying Tasks directly?

Tags: apex, soql, activities, tasks

I am running the code below in a Task trigger.  The subquery on Account returns 0 rows, but the direct Task query returns 1 row; there should be 1 row.  Can someone explain why this could be happening.  Thanks!

```
            List<Task> debugTaskList = [select activityDate from Task
                       where ownerId <> :excludedId and isClosed = true
                      and activityDate != null and AccountId = :acctId
                        order by activityDate desc nulls last limit 1];

            List<Account> debugAcctList = [select Id,
                              (select activityDate 
                              from Tasks
                              where ownerId <> :excludedId and isClosed = true
                             and activityDate != null
                              order by activityDate desc nulls last limit 1)
                           from Account where id = :acctId];

            system.assert(false, 'acctList = ' + debugAcctList[0].Tasks.size() 
                              + ', taskList = ' + debugTaskList.size());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Background**

Very interesting question, it seems like what you're doing should work just fine.  After some further investigation it appears that the `Tasks` child relationship subquery only returns tasks directly related to accounts by `Task.WhatId` where as your direct query will return all tasks related to the account by `Task.AccountId` (which is a formula field that gets set for tasks related to accounts, contacts, cases, and opportunities for a particular account). In your example, my guess is one of the tasks returned in your direct query is related to a contact, case, or opportunity).

Fortunately there are a couple other *virtual* child relationship subqueries that should work for you depending on your use case (I got these details for the [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php)).  Given you're querying closed activities you'll want to use ActivityHistories.

**Tasks**

- Relationship Name: Tasks
- Child sObject: Task
- Field: WhatId

**Open Activities**

- Relationship Name: OpenActivities
- Child sObject: OpenActivity (really just activity, a polymorphic event and task)
- Field: AccountId

**Activity History**

- Relationship Name: ActivityHistories
- Child sObject: ActivityHistory (again, just an Activity)
- Field: AccountId

Comment: Thanks, Ralph!  The debug queries now agree.  I'll see if the actual code behaves correctly now.  JimH

Answer (score 1):

```
(select activityDate from Tasks
```

I believe the problem is that you're selecting `activityDate` from Tasks instead of `Activity History`. I don't show `activityDate` as being a valid related field in `Tasks` from `Account`. Instead, it only appears `in ActivityHistory`.

**EDIT**

The above was clearly a mistake from when I didn't click the API level names box in Force.com Explorer when checking my Dev Org. Please accept my apologies.

Taking another look...

```
from Tasks where ownerId <> :excludedId and isClosed = true and activityDate != null
```

You may want to break this part of your query up into something that looks more like

```
from Tasks where ownerId != (:excludedId AND isClosed = true AND activityDate != null)
```

There may be something about it picking up the value of `excludedId` and applying the `value of` operator to `isClosed` and/or the `activityDate` differently in one query than it does the other. I also have a preference for using `!=` logical operator over the `<>` operator. I'd think that would at least be worth trying.

Comment: ActivityDate is a valid field on Task.  Shouldn't the subquery return all the tasks and the queried Task fields for the account?

Comment: My bad, I had the wrong checkbox clicked when I looked at my DevOrg and created the query. It is indeed a valid field! Without knowing what :excludedId is I can't say if it would return all tasks or not.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Changing to != and grouping in parentheses had no effect.  The excludedId is just a single user Id we do not want to include in the query.  Since excludedId is used in the same way in both queries, its specific value is not relevant to the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: One observation, you have a clearly defined double bind on the 1st query, but it's more of an implicit double bind on the 2nd query. Perhaps that's the actual difference between the two that's causing the discrepancy. If you can reconstruct the query to change the binding, that might somehow change your results. The only other thing that comes to mind to try would be to remove the order by clause to see if it makes any difference. I wouldn't expect it to, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by double bind.  Can you tell me what part of the code you are referring to?  Thanks.

Comment: In your 1st query -> debugTaskList = [select activityDate from Task `where ownerId <> :excludedId and isClosed = true and activityDate != null` (1st direct set of binds) **and** `AccountId = :acctId` (direct final or 2nd bind). In your 2nd query -> debugAcctList = [select Id, (select activityDate from Tasks 'where ownerId <> :excludedId and isClosed = true and activityDate != null` **(same 1st set of direct binds on inner query)** `from Account where id =:acctId` **(now an indirect "outer", 2nd or "double" bind vs being an inner bind)**. Do you see the difference in structure?

Comment: OK, thanks.  But I need these queries to be structured the way they are (the second one is used as a summary and I need to avoid too many rows error; the first one will be used as a drill down page, which will show all the tasks, upto 100 rows).  These debug queries demonstrate the issue I'm seeing, not the final way I will be implementing my code.  Bottom line is, I need to get this structure to work.